# Is there a way to make standalone GUI app using Julia?

Tags: julia, gtk

I'm trying to learn Julia instead of Matlab and Python cause it is easy, fast, free.
One of my purposes is to make a standalone GUI app using Julia.
So, I tried making a simple app using Gtk (PackageCompiler), but Gtk is not relocatable and executable. it is so depressing.

Cannot make a standalone GUI app using Julia?
When would it be possible?

*How about using Golang for science and making GUI app?

Answer (score 0):

There are [numerous GUI packages](https://juliapackages.com/c/gui) for julia. If you have problems specifically with Gtk, you have to provide more details.

Releasing standalone applications using julia has been of low priority so far (2023/02) since in scientific applications it's usually fine to just distribute the source code package or a container. However, you can still build standalone julia applications using [PackageCompiler.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl).

Comment: I think Manu is asking for which packages play nicely with PackageCompiler.jl, as gtk (rather, GTK3) doesn't usually work well in compiled sysimages.